# Multiple Viewmodels/Views of single DataModel

Tags: c#, mvvm

I've gotten to know MVVM and believe I understand the concepts behind it. However, something I've yet to be seen being documented well is the "Model" in MVVM. The following situtation seems to arise constantly and I haven't found a satisfying way to deal with it:

The Models (Simplified):

```
class School{
   public List<Classroom> Classrooms{get;set;}
}
class Classroom{
   public List<Student> Students{get;set;}
}

class Student{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The ViewModels (Simplified):

```
class SchoolViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   School School;
   ObservableCollection<ClassroomViewModel>ClassroomListItemViewModels{get;set;}
   ClassroomDetailViewModel ClassroomDetailViewModel{get;set;}
}

class ClassroomDetailViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
   Classroom Classroom;

   int NumberOfStudents {get; set}
   ObservableCollection<Student> StudentListItemViewModel{get;set;}
   StudentDetailViewModel StudentDetailViewModel{get;set;}
}

ClassroomListItemViewModel:BaseViewModel{
   Classroom Classroom;
   int NumberOfStudents {get; set}
}

class StudentListItemViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
   Student Student;

   string Name{get; set}

}
class StudentDetailViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
   Student Student;

   string Name{get; set}

}
```

(Leaving out INotifyPropertyChanged for simplicity..)

The Views:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQmVv.jpg

The SchoolView shows a list of the classrooms, a detail view of the selected classroom. The classroom detail view shows a list of student views, as well as a detail view of the selected student

The desired behaviour:
Changes in the model should propagate across all views/viewmodels showing that model.
My approaches:
1) Add INotifyPropertyChanged or something similar to the model
->This pollutes my model

2) Add an Update() method to each viewmodel, which rebuilds it from the model. 
->Requires that someoneone keeps track of when the model changes, and also knows which viewmodels are affected by this change

3)Add a ModelChanged Event to some global context to which Viewmodels can subscribe, and also ask to raise the event.
->When removing a ListItemViewModel, one must remember to unsubscribe it from the context to prevent a memory leak

The desired behaviour:
Changes in the Viewmodel should be able to be stored in the Model at some point
My Approaches:
1)ViewModels have a StoreToModel() method which applies changes to the model
->how to notify all other viewmodels that depend on that model that something has changed

2)Some overarching context decides when to save data changes
->lots of logic in the "top" of the heirarchy as it must control everything

Essentially all of this boils down to two topologies, pyramid and star shaped.
The pyramid pushes changes down through a hierarchy of viewmodels, while the star shaped consists of some global context 
to which all viewmodels can publish and subscribe their changes

Personally I prefer the global context as it allows me to add viewmodels flexibly, so long as they hold an instance of this context.

```
//Point of intersection between many viewmodels
class ModelContext
{
   public void ModelChanged(object model){
        ModelChangedEvent.Invoke(model);
   }

   public event ModelChangedEventHandler ModelChangedEvent;
}
```

One downside I've found is that I must take care to avoid memory leaks (for example when I remove a
ViewModel from a Collection I must also remember to unsubscribe it)

Is there some sort of Pattern ive missed that just makes every work?
How about my global ModelContext? Is there something inherently wrong with this?

Comment: "Changes in the model should propagate across all views/viewmodels showing that model" -- nope. The model classes are just bare sets of properties for getting data from the data store and sending it back. When it's time to save to the database, a viewmodel whips up a model representation of itself and sends that to some data layer method (also part of "the model") which stuffs it in a table or XML or something Also, what kind of change would be propagated from one viewmodel to another?

Comment: In the example above the name of a Student might be found in the StudentListItemViewModel or in the StudentDetailViewModel. When changing that name, it should reflect on both ViewModels.

Comment: Why would you have two different viewmodels for the same thing? The StudentViewModel represents the student. You don't need two of them. How or why is a student displayed in a list a different thing from a student elsewhere?

Comment: Well going by the mantra of having one viewmodel per view, if i wish to display some data in two views, I must find a way to keep these two viewmodels in synch. And showing the same data in multiple views is something that pops up quite often.

Comment: Wow I honestly don't know where I picked that up. Such a simple solution